# Создать двумерный массив из строки

Tags: java, массивы

есть строка в файле `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`
из `java.util.Arrays` `Arrays.deepToString(deepArray)`, и мне нужно превратить эту строку двумерный массив `int[][]`

как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение "на коленке"

```
 //Разбиваем по сиволу "]," - получаем массив
 int[][] toArray = Arrays.stream(s.split("],"))
                //убираем лишние символы
                .map((str) -> str.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
                //разбиваем теперь по , - получаем ещё массив
                .map((str) -> str.split(","))
                //преобразовываем значения каждого полученного массива в int[]
                .map((str) -> Arrays.stream(str).mapToInt((val) -> Integer.valueOf(val.trim())).toArray())
                 //группируем в массив
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
```